# UITableView Indexed list populated from server json

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a large amount(10000 records) of data that i am pulling in from server in json format.  This data has no hierarchal component so just want to show alphabetically in a UITableView with alpha IndexBar on side. Is there a way to lazy/load the data when an index is clicked. I was thinking of adding some logic to sectionForSectionIndexTitle to call server for that letter's records.  Any successful implementations doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the new iOS7 table view property `estimatedRowHeight`, you can achieve this quite easily. All you should know is how many sections there are, how many rows there and only load a small amount around the request sections/rows by the table view. So once the view loads, you will load some data around `A` and so on. Once the user taps an index, the table view will ask for a different section and row, allowing you to throw the previous information and load some around the newly displayed cells.

One ceveat, rows should be of same height, or it's a big mess.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i was thinking but what about when a user slides the alpha index bar. Sounds like could get tricky with staring/canceling network requests. Is it possible to disable the slide behavior with index bar?

Comment: @user1499528 Did you implement?

Answer (score 0):

the best approach would be have your server support paging and query by alphabet. Loading 10k item at once and transform them into object is gonna have a major impact on your app.

Or you can have your app download that data once and then store that data on your local system using Core Data. So you don't need to fetch from server every time.

Comment: Doing a large fetch is very doable if you prepare the data in SQL before outputting from the web-service.  I do this with around a 9K recordset.  Paging is a bad idea (multiple calls and if for some reason, the network is unavailable, you would wind up with a partial list).  Also, saving to CoreData is going to be an intensive operation, saving to NSUserDefaults works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I load around 9000 records from a single SQL call and load these into an `NSArray` (I use AFNetworking to do the async network stuff).  I have no issues with speed.  I also cache the array of dictionaries (my data is for a phonebook) using `NSUserDefaults`, so that the next time the app calls the web-service for fresh data, the tableview data is already present and loaded from the array in `NSUserDefaults`.  Then after the request finishes, I compare the array loaded from `NSUserDefaults` with the fresh array from the web-service, if the objects are the same, I do nothing otherwise I reload the tableview with the fresh data.

I do a couple of special things on the SQL side like doing the ordering and also using single character keys for the dictionary objects (like `{a:FirstNameValue,b:LastNameValue,c:PhoneNumberValue...}`

This process is really fast especially on subsequent loads.  I actually pre-load the array on first launch while the user is logging in for the first time.  Most of the time, when the user is done logging in, the phone web-service call is done.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!